# How do I parse getStyle request?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, sld, request

I am having problem parsing

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetStyles&layers=topp%3Astates&service=wms&version=1.1.1
```

getStyle response  from geoserver of layer topp:states.
I want to get the SLD information of a layer with openlayers. I get blank response for the following request. The response parsed SLD file has no value.
**For now I am doing :**

```
var json = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON();
    OpenLayers.Request.GET({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
             params: {request: "GetStyles",layers:"topp:states",service:"wms",version:"1.1.1"},
            success: complete
        });

        function complete(req) {
        //console.log(req);
            sld = format.read(req.responseXML || req.responseText);
            //console.log("The sld");
            //console.log(sld.namedLayers);
            //styles = sld.namedLayers.interpreted.userStyles[0];
            //console.log(styles);
           // building_vec.styleMap.styles.default = styles;
           console.log(json.write(sld, true));

    }
```

**The response:**

```
{
    "namedLayers": {
    },
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

**But when I hit direct requested url I get right sld.**

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetStyles&layers=topp%3Astates&service=wms&version=1.1.1
```

**The SLD with url directly on address bar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
    <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>topp:states</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>population</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title>Population in the United States</sld:Title>
            <sld:IsDefault>1</sld:IsDefault>
            <sld:Abstract>A sample filter that filters the United States into three
        categories of population, drawn in different colors</sld:Abstract>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>&lt; 2M</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>2000000</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#4DFF4D</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>2M - 4M</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>2000000</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>4000000</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF4D4D</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>&gt; 4M</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>4000000</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#4D4DFF</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>Boundary</sld:Title>
                    <sld:LineSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:LineSymbolizer>
                    <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Label>
                        <sld:Font>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">14</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Font>
                        <sld:LabelPlacement>
                            <sld:PointPlacement>
                                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointX>
                                        <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
                                    </sld:AnchorPointX>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointY>
                                        <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
                                    </sld:AnchorPointY>
                                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                                <sld:Rotation>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
                                </sld:Rotation>
                            </sld:PointPlacement>
                        </sld:LabelPlacement>
                    </sld:TextSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>pophatch</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title>Population in the United States</sld:Title>
            <sld:Abstract>A sample filter that filters the United States into three
        categories of population, drawn in different colors</sld:Abstract>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>&lt; 2M</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>2000000</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:GraphicFill>
                                <sld:Graphic>
                                    <sld:Mark>
                                        <sld:WellKnownName>shape://slash</sld:WellKnownName>
                                        <sld:Stroke>
                                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">0xAAAAAA</sld:CssParameter>
                                        </sld:Stroke>
                                    </sld:Mark>
                                    <sld:Size>
                                        <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
                                    </sld:Size>
                                </sld:Graphic>
                            </sld:GraphicFill>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>2M - 4M</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>2000000</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>4000000</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:GraphicFill>
                                <sld:Graphic>
                                    <sld:Mark>
                                        <sld:WellKnownName>shape://slash</sld:WellKnownName>
                                        <sld:Stroke>
                                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">0xAAAAAA</sld:CssParameter>
                                        </sld:Stroke>
                                    </sld:Mark>
                                    <sld:Size>
                                        <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
                                    </sld:Size>
                                </sld:Graphic>
                            </sld:GraphicFill>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>&gt; 4M</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>4000000</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:GraphicFill>
                                <sld:Graphic>
                                    <sld:Mark>
                                        <sld:WellKnownName>shape://slash</sld:WellKnownName>
                                        <sld:Stroke>
                                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">0xAAAAAA</sld:CssParameter>
                                        </sld:Stroke>
                                    </sld:Mark>
                                    <sld:Size>
                                        <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                                    </sld:Size>
                                </sld:Graphic>
                            </sld:GraphicFill>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Title>Boundary</sld:Title>
                    <sld:LineSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Stroke/>
                    </sld:LineSymbolizer>
                    <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Label>
                        <sld:Font>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">14</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Font>
                        <sld:LabelPlacement>
                            <sld:PointPlacement>
                                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointX>
                                        <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
                                    </sld:AnchorPointX>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointY>
                                        <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
                                    </sld:AnchorPointY>
                                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                                <sld:Rotation>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
                                </sld:Rotation>
                            </sld:PointPlacement>
                        </sld:LabelPlacement>
                        <sld:Halo>
                            <sld:Radius>
                                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                            </sld:Radius>
                            <sld:Fill>
                                <sld:CssParameter name="fill">0xFFFFFF</sld:CssParameter>
                            </sld:Fill>
                        </sld:Halo>
                    </sld:TextSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>polygon</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title>Default Polygon</sld:Title>
            <sld:Abstract>A sample style that draws a polygon</sld:Abstract>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>rule1</sld:Name>
                    <sld:Title>Gray Polygon with Black Outline</sld:Title>
                    <sld:Abstract>A polygon with a gray fill and a 1 pixel black outline</sld:Abstract>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#AAAAAA</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                        <sld:Stroke/>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Can you post your expected request  response? What should the request have returned?

Comment: @R.K. There is the requred SLD.

Comment: Why do you want to do that btw?

Comment: @R.K. Actually I want to know how the layer is styled using what column name of table. So that I can find feature hits using wfs query.Feature Count

Comment: First thing to check is whether the two requests being sent are exactly the same. Could you confirm that the OpenLayers request string is the same as the one that produces the correct response.

Comment: @pecoanddeco yes they are the same. http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetStyles&layers=topp%3Astates&service=wms&version=1.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem is in the line breaks from Geoserver XML indent.

It works when I do something like below

```
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
    params: {
        request: "GetStyles",
        layers: "topp:states",
        service: "wms",
        version: "1.1.1"
    },
    success: function (data, statut, xhr) {
        var format = new OpenLayers.Format.SLD();
        //Trick is to clean line break
        var obj = format.read(data.responseText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""));
        //Js object
        console.log(obj);
        var json = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON();
        // Object converted to json for readability but not really useful at js level
        console.log(json.write(obj, true));
    }
});
```

**Edit**

When I do my test going to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp:states&styles=&bbox=-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735&width=780&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers`, it failed.

I solved the problem by replacing the file OpenLayers.js into the geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/wms-2.3.1.jar with the http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js (because the default built-in Openlayers library in Geoserver don't have OpenLayers.Format.SLD() and OpenLayers.Format.JSON())

If you don't want to change anything but only confirm it works just try with this other ajax request

```
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
    params: {
        request: "GetStyles",
        layers: "topp:states",
        service: "wms",
        version: "1.1.1"
    },
    success: function (data, statut, xhr) {
        var format = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
        //Trick is to clean line break
        var obj = format.read(data.responseText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""));
        //Dom object to manipulate yourself
        console.log(obj);
        //Try that you can convert the XML object back to text
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
        //For Internet Explorer:
            var string = obj.xml;
        } else {
            var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(obj);
        }
        console.log(string)
    }
});
```

If you always have a blank answer with code below, look on the Cross Domain Policy matter. It's a common problem with ajax calls. See http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html

Comment: The response is still blank. Both xml and json. Did you get the response?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: It was all beacause of Cross Domain Policy.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is the same then there must be an issue with the code that's dealing with the response.

Comparing your code to that on the [OpenLayers](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html) documentation there is some difference. The documentation uses the 'callback' parameter rather than 'success', not sure if that would make a difference or not, or whether it's just a difference in versions.

The other thing to check is what the value of req.responseXML is before you convert it into JSON.

Try something like the following and see what you get:

```
function handler(req) {
    alert(req.responseXML);
}

OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
    params: {request: "GetStyles",layers:"topp:states",service:"wms",version:"1.1.1"},
    callback: handler
});
```

Comment: I have changed success to handler. It doesn't matter. xml response is null.

Comment: How are you checking the request string that your code is creating? Seems like there must be an issue there if you're getting different responses back.

Comment: I am checking it using firebug. It's same.