# How to get Legend Information from a WMS server?

Tags: geoserver, wms, legend

I need to get the Legend Information from Geoserver in JSON or XML format, so that I can display it in my App in a custom way.

I'm basically looking for something equivalent to https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/index.html?mslegend.html in the OGC world.

The Image provided by [GetLegendGraphics](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#get-legend-graphic) does not meet my requirements.

Is it possible to get Legend Information information in JSON/XML format?

Comment: I think that the answer is no, see http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Getting-the-Legend-as-JSON-td5256985.html

Comment: There was a GISP (http://old.geoserver.org/GSIP%2081%20-%20GetLegendGraphic%20as%20text%20(JSON).html) but it doesn't look finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WMS + SLD servers the closest operation to the ArcGIS API call is **GetStyles**.

A request would look like:

```
http://your/server/.../ows?
  service=WMS&
  VERSION=1.3.0&
  request=GetStyles&
  Layers=your-layer&
  sld_version=1.1.0&
```

Response is XML.

Comment: This Answer along with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59533/how-do-i-parse-getstyle-request gives the complete solution